# Find the following using either substitution, integration by parts, or a table.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm kind of worried I did the question wrong, so I was hoping someone could reassure me. The question says
 ***Find the following using either substitution, integration by parts, or a table.***

1. $\int \left(1-x\right)\sqrt{x}dx$
2. $\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx$

So for 1.

$=\int \sqrt{x}-x^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$

$\int \sqrt{x}dx-\int \:x^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$

$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}$

$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}+C$

> I did not use substitution but I used the sum rule. The question did
>   not ask for that, so would that mean that my answer is wrong?

For the 2nd Q

$\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx$

let $\:u=x+1$

$\int \frac{1}{u}du$

$\ln \left|u\right|$

$\ln \left|x+1\right|+C$

> I am never sure about substitutions but in this case I need to use
>   substitution like this right?

Comment: All your answers are correct. In any case it would be unreasonable for a professor to downgrade you for using the sum rule without being explicitly asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers look reasonable to me. Perhaps the "table" refers to a table of common integrals? Otherwise, I'm not sure why any of those would be necessary for the first.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the power rule can be said to come from an integration table, so you should be fine on #1. And for #2 you used substitution, so all is well!

If you professor is really picky, when you go to do your substitution, it may help to show the statement $du=dx$ somewhere, even though it is painfully obvious.